# XML displaying ["num_rows"]=> int(0)

Tags: javascript, sql, laravel

i have this code i tried to var_dump results i get number of roes is 0

**object(mysqli_result)#294 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(10) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> int(0) }**

```
// Search the rows in the restaurants table
   $query = sprintf("SELECT  physical_address,opening_time,closing_time,days_of_operation,website,email,phone, lng, lat, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM restaurants HAVING distance < '%s' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20",
  mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$center_lat),
  mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$center_lng),
  mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$center_lat),
  mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$radius));

   $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
   $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
   if (!$result) {
     die("Invalid query: " .mysqli_error($connection));

   }
   else {var_dump($result);}

  // $roww = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
  // echo $roww;

  // echo @mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
     $node = $dom->createElement("restaurant");
     $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
```

Comment: Is your query returning results when you execute it directly?

Comment: I recreated your `restaurants` table and inserted a few rows. When I execute I see `["num_rows"]=> int(2)`.